# List of domains required to pull Docker image

Tags: proxy, docker

I'm on a network with limited internet access and I need to provide a list of domains to allow to pull docker images.

In the first place I thought `https://registry-1.docker.io/` would be enough but trying to pull an image, it seems that `https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/` is also required so the question is: is there a list of all the domains to allow to pull images from the public docker registry?

Comment: As a workaround, you can download the docker image with `docker save` in a device where you have network access and import it to the restricted device with `docker load`.

Comment: Found additional sources of info besides the one mentioned in the top-voted answer: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubeflow-distribution/issues/34 https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/whitelist-the-following-if-your-docker-registry-is-behind-firewalls-and-proxy-servers/

Comment: There is also a related question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34726683/2157640

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The article
[Whitelisting Docker Hub Hosts for Firewalls and HTTP Proxy Servers](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015442847-Whitelisting-Docker-Hub-Hosts-for-Firewalls-and-HTTP-Proxy-Servers)
contains this list:

```
https://auth.docker.io
https://registry-1.docker.io
https://index.docker.io/
https://dseasb33srnrn.cloudfront.net/
https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/
```

Comment: can anyone confirm that dseasb33srnrn.cloudfront.net is still needed? Trying to reduce Firewall (FW) rules

Comment: @Tilo Was wondering if you determined whether dseasb33srnrn.cloudfront.net is still required?

Comment: @daniel nope didn't determine this.

Answer (score 1):

This is my whitelist domains I have found:

```
https://auth.docker.io<br/>
https://registry.docker.io<br/>
https://registry-1.docker.io<br/>
https://registry-2.docker.io<br/>
https://index.docker.io<br/>
https://dseasb33srnrn.cloudfront.net<br>
https://production.cloudflare.docker.com
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Documentation page](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/allow-list/) for Docker Desktop, the following URLs need to be allowlisted:

For Push/Pull:

```
https://hub.docker.com
https://registry-1.docker.io
https://production.cloudflare.docker.com
```

For Authentication:

```
https://auth.docker.io
https://cdn.auth0.com
https://login.docker.com
```